# If, else statement with Twilio. I want to use a different response based on my query result

Tags: php, twilio

My query will either exist or not exist. If it does it exist, my row counter is 1 but if it does not exist the row counter is 0. I am trying to use a response based on the row counter's value. See below. If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears.

```
if ($rowcounter==1){

echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
echo "<Response><Say>Welcome" . $companyname . "</Say></Response>";

}

else

{

echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
echo "<Response><Say>We could not locate your customer number</Say></Response>";

}
```

Removing the code within the else brackets allows the code to work fine but I'm not sure how to get my else statement working.

Comment: what error are you facing ? if $rowcounter == 0 then the else statement is not executed or what  ?

Comment: it never makes it past the if statement. I get a twilio error. Are there any other ways to do a conditional statement. And does the </Response> end the ability to add any other responses.

Comment: you definatly have to post the twilio error, you are just echoing strings

Comment: Are you certain your PHP is actually getting executed and returning valid TwiML?  Does the error happen regardless of if the first if condition is met?  Have you tried creating an endpoint that always returns the first response, then one that always returns the second response, and verified that both work?  Also, your first echo line in each block doesn't escape the double quote characters within the string properly.

Answer (score 1):

you could shorten it using ternary operator

```
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
echo "<Response><Say>".$rowcounter == 1 ? "Welcome".$companyname : "We could not locate your customer number"."</Say></Response>";
```